# Как установить запуск скрипта по расписанию в Android Nougat?

Tags: android, shell, cron

Всем привет, необходимо каждые полчаса выполнять некоторые действия с помощью скрипта в `/system/bin`. Каким образом это можно сделать? В BusyBox есть утилита `crond` но я не смог разобраться как ей пользоваться. Для теста хочется просто создать папку

```
mkdir /sdcard/cron
```

Comment: @0xdb, ошибочка )

Comment: AlarmManager посмотрите

Comment: @Соколов, нееее. именно скрипт, вообще не приложение